# sqlite - Issue with iterating over a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have a dictionary with ID's and iterate over them to **scrape** some data create a DB and then make certain calculations in pandas.
I run into an issue on that last part.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3


team_ids = {
    'BUD': ['3163', '2111'],
    'OLI': ['883', '2657']
}

for team_id in team_ids.values():
    for team in team_ids.keys():
        for player_id in team_id:
            conn = sqlite3.connect('DBs/' + f'{team}' + '/' + f'id{player_id}' + '.db')
            c = conn.cursor()
            df = pd.read_sql_query("select * from Player", conn)
```

If I run each keys separately, either BUD or OLI, it works fine but as soon as I try to do both I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/qq88/python-virtual-environments/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1595, in execute
    cur.execute(*args)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Player

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calculate.py", line 27, in <module>
    df = pd.read_sql_query("select * from Player", conn)
  File "/home/qq88/python-virtual-environments/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 332, in read_sql_query
    chunksize=chunksize,
  File "/home/qq88/python-virtual-environments/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1645, in read_query
    cursor = self.execute(*args)
  File "/home/qq88/python-virtual-environments/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1610, in execute
    raise_with_traceback(ex)
  File "/home/qq88/python-virtual-environments/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 47, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
  File "/home/qq88/python-virtual-environments/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1595, in execute
    cur.execute(*args)
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select * from Player': no such table: Player
```

tree:

```
.
├── calculate.py
├── CSVs
│   ├── BUD.csv
│   └── OLI.csv
├── DBs
│   ├── BUD
│   │   ├── id2111.db
│   │   └── id3163.db
│   └── OLI
│       ├── id2657.db
│       └── id883.db
```

I noticed that when I run the code with both keys I suddenly get a duplicate`id2111.db` in the OLI folder despite it belonging to the other one. Maybe I messed up the iteration somehow?

EDIT:
When I run the script it creates the 2111.db in the other folder, this one being empty and hence throws an error. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7PTl.png)

Does `df = pd.read_sql_query("select * from Player", conn)` open all the DB's at once? I assumed it goes one by one and matches them accordingly.

Comment: The error you are getting is that you don't have a table named *Player* in the database. It has nothing to do with `pandas` nor your `dictionary`

Comment: Print the connection string you are using in the inner loop, and see on which one it fails.

Comment: I certainly have the table in there. As mentioned above, it works fine when I use the keys separately and I am using the same DB then. But when I have both keys it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was iterating too much and pulling the wrong data.

Instead of:

```
for team_id in team_ids.values():
    for team in team_ids.keys():
        for player_id in team_id:
```

I just had to do:

```
for team in team_ids:
    for player in team_ids[team]:
```